# What is the difference between these sentences (usage of "upload")?

Tags: clauses

> I am unable to upload a file in my computer, what i want to upload.

> I am unable to upload a file in my computer that i want to upload.

What is the difference between these sentences written above?

Comment: *What* makes the former ungrammatical. For the latter, you can use either *that* or *which*. I find the sentence a bit wordy and the part *"that I want to upload"* unnecessary. Also, we use a different preposition with *upload* - if you upload something, you transfer it from one place **to** another.

Comment: Don't you mean download? Upload or download a file TO a place.

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to upload a file in my computer that I want to upload.

That one is OK but the other one is not. This one would also work with *which* instead of *that* as AndrewTobilko pointed out in a comment.

However it would be clearer to say

> I am unable to upload a file from my computer

using *from* rather than *in* and deleting the last part since it does not really add any extra information.